# Simple Rust Webserver

Tags: beginner, file, http, rust, server

I started learning Rust today and for my first project created a simple webserver.

I don't have a clear vision about Rust programming and I tried to write it with my previous knowledge in Python and PHP.

```
use std::io::{Read, Write,BufReader, BufRead};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;


fn main(){
    loop{
        let listener = TcpListener::bind("localhost:8000").unwrap();
        let stream  = listener.accept().unwrap().0;
        read_request(stream);
    }
}

fn read_request(stream: TcpStream){

    let mut lines = String::new();
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(stream);
    reader.read_line(&mut lines);
    let mut vec_line = lines.split_whitespace();
    let mut requested_page = vec_line.nth(1).unwrap().to_string();
    requested_page = requested_page.replace("/","");
    if requested_page == "" {
        requested_page = String::from("index.html");
    }
    let mut response = String::new();
    let path = Path::new(&requested_page);
    println!("{}",requested_page);
    let mut status = 200;
    if !path.exists(){
        response = String::from("Not Found!");
        status = 404;
    } else {
        let mut file = File::open(&requested_page).expect("Unable to open file");
        file.read_to_string(&mut response);
    }

    send_response(reader.into_inner(), &response.to_string(), status);

}

fn send_response(mut stream: TcpStream, res :&str, status :u32){
    let response = format!("{}{}{}{}","HTTP/1.1 ",status," OK\n\n",res);
    stream.write_all(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Learn to love [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt):

   1. Spaces go between comma-separated items:

      ```
      -use std::io::{Read, Write,BufReader, BufRead};
      +use std::io::{Read, Write, BufReader, BufRead};
      ```

      ```
      -let response = format!("{}{}{}{}","HTTP/1.1 ",status," OK\n\n",res);
      +let response = format!("{}{}{}{}", "HTTP/1.1 ", status, " OK\n\n", res);
      ```
   2. Spaces go before braces:

      ```
      -fn main(){
      +fn main() {
      ```

      ```
      -loop{
      +loop {
      ```
   3. Colons attach on the left side of type definitions:

      ```
      -fn send_response(mut stream: TcpStream, res :&str, status :u32){
      +fn send_response(mut stream: TcpStream, res: &str, status: u32) {
      ```
2. **Pay attention to compiler warnings**. One of the entire purposes of using a compiled language is to have the compiler watch your back. If you ignore it, then what good is it?

   ```
   warning: unused result which must be used, #[warn(unused_must_use)] on by default
     --> src/main.rs:19:5
      |
   19 |     reader.read_line(&mut lines);
      |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   warning: unused result which must be used, #[warn(unused_must_use)] on by default
     --> src/main.rs:35:9
      |
   35 |         file.read_to_string(&mut response);
      |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
3. Introduce more functions to break up the distinct parts of `read_request`. From my inspection, there's a part that parses the request, a part that handles the request by reading a file, and a part that responds (which already exists). Note that doing this contrains the number of lines of code a variable is mutable and avoids the need to recover the inner `TcpStream` from the `BufReader`.
4. `vec_line` is poorly named; it's not a `Vec`. I *am* happy to see your use of `nth`; many people would `collect` into a `Vec`, which is inefficient.
5. There's no reason to convert the result of `nth` into a `String`, you can call `replace` on a `&str` equally as well.
6. Avoid using `mut` just to be able to reassign a variable (e.g. the result of `replace`). Instead, just bind the variable a second time. This reduces the amount and scope of mutability.
7. `requested_page == ""` should be `requested_page.is_empty()`
8. Why would you convert a `String` to a `String` using `to_string`? Just take a reference to the existing string.
9. There's no need to create a string to write to the stream; just `write!` directly to the stream.
10. The code always prints "OK", regardless of the status.
11. Checking if a file exists before reading it introduces a race where the file can be deleted between the check and the read. It's better to open the file and check any resulting error.
12. Instead of creating mutable variables (`response`, `status`) with defaults, consider only setting them in the appropriate branches. Again, this reduces the number of mutable variables and the scopes of mutability.
13. Once `response` and `status` are moved to a function, you can just return them directly.
14. `read_request` does more than just *read*, so it should be renamed.
15. The current code doesn't require a `TcpStream` except in the outermost loop. It only needs anything that implements `Read` and `Write`. Using generics will allow you to more easily test those functions in isolation.

```
use std::io::{self, Read, Write, BufReader, BufRead};
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    loop {
        let listener = TcpListener::bind("localhost:8000").unwrap();
        let stream = listener.accept().unwrap().0;
        handle_request(stream);
    }
}

fn handle_request<S>(mut stream: S)
    where S: Read + Write
{
    let requested_page = parse_request(&mut stream);
    let (response, status) = read_file(&requested_page);
    send_response(stream, &response, status);
}

fn parse_request<R>(stream: R) -> String
    where R: Read
{
    let mut line = String::new();

    let mut reader = BufReader::new(stream);
    reader.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();

    let mut words = line.split_whitespace();
    let requested_page = words.nth(1).unwrap();
    let requested_page = requested_page.replace("/", "");

    if requested_page.is_empty() {
        String::from("index.html")
    } else {
        requested_page
    }
}

fn read_file(requested_page: &str) -> (String, u32) {
    match File::open(&requested_page) {
        Ok(mut file) => {
            let mut s = String::new();
            file.read_to_string(&mut s).unwrap();
            (s, 200)
        }
        Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::NotFound => (String::from("Not Found!"), 404),
        Err(e) => panic!("Unable to open file: {}", e),
    }
}

fn send_response<W>(mut stream: W, res: &str, status: u32)
    where W: Write
{
    write!(&mut stream, "{}{}{}{}", "HTTP/1.1 ", status, " OK\n\n", res).unwrap();
}
```

There are *way* too many uses of `unwrap`. At the *very* least, use `expect` so you have some clue about what caused the program to terminate. Even better, use [`Result` for error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html).

As a basic step, returning a `Box<Error>` is extremely simple and allows you to consolidate your error handling:

```
use std::io::{self, Read, Write, BufReader, BufRead};
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::fs::File;

type Error = Box<std::error::Error>;
type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Error>;

fn main() {
    loop {
        if let Err(e) = handle_one("localhost:8000") {
            panic!("An error occurred, I'm exiting! {}", e);
        }
    }
}

fn handle_one(address: &str) -> Result<()> {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(address)?;
    let stream = listener.accept()?.0;
    handle_request(stream)
}

fn handle_request<S>(mut stream: S) -> Result<()>
    where S: Read + Write
{
    let requested_page = parse_request(&mut stream)?;
    let (response, status) = read_file(&requested_page)?;
    send_response(stream, &response, status)
}

fn parse_request<R>(stream: R) -> Result<String>
    where R: Read,
{
    let mut line = String::new();

    let mut reader = BufReader::new(stream);
    reader.read_line(&mut line)?;

    let mut words = line.split_whitespace();
    let requested_page = words.nth(1).ok_or("request missing path")?;
    let requested_page = requested_page.replace("/", "");

    if requested_page.is_empty() {
        Ok(String::from("index.html"))
    } else {
        Ok(requested_page)
    }
}

fn read_file(requested_page: &str) -> Result<(String, u32)> {
    match File::open(&requested_page) {
        Ok(mut file) => {
            let mut s = String::new();
            file.read_to_string(&mut s)?;
            Ok((s, 200))
        },
        Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::NotFound => {
            Ok((String::from("Not Found!"), 404))
        }
        Err(e) => Err(e.into()),
    }
}

fn send_response<W>(mut stream: W, res: &str, status: u32) -> Result<()>
    where W: Write,
{
    write!(&mut stream, "{}{}{}{}", "HTTP/1.1 ", status, " OK\n\n", res)?;
    Ok(())
}
```